# Jest React Cannot read property 'createEvent' of undefined on setState

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typeerror, jestjs

My component should retrieve a list of locations when the user logs in.
I'm using `fetch-mock` to mock the fetch request and return some data that the component is going to use when mounting.

```
class Comp extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLocations();
    }

    getLocations = () => {
        const url = 'the-url';

        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(json => {
                // json = {"value": [{"id": 0, "name": "Test Location"}]
                this.setState({
                    locations: json.value
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('getLocations err', err))
    };
}
```

I've logged the json and the input is as defined in the comment.

The error I'm getting is `getLocations err TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of undefined`.

The line given on the bottom of the callstack is the `this.setState({locations: json.value});` and logging `this` shows me the instance of the react component as expected.

Can anyone help me with this?

Tech:

- react 16.2.0
- jest 21.2.1
- react-test-renderer 16.2.0
- babel-jest 21.2.0

Comment: Sounds like this issue on GitHub may be related: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3482

Comment: Although I do think it's related, I'm not having async/await issues, as I resolve the fetch in the `.then` and handle it from there.

Comment: I think we need more context --- What does your test file look like? How are you initializing your mock? What should be defined and have a createEvent method?

Comment: was this ever figured out?

Comment: This issue is caused by Jest having torn the DOM away while the component is still doing some async work. One possible solution is to make the Jest test case async as well, for example using `done`. Another solution is to mock `fetch` as suggested above.